# Ubuntu licensing terms

Tags: license

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to understand how the licensing works.
  Is it free to download for anyone and to install anywhere??  We need to install Ubuntu on our mainframe at work, so I need to make sure we are fully compliant and that I understand the licensing terms.
It looks as though it is free to install and use , but then i have seen on the website about paying $19,500 per drawer per year  - which has now confused me!  It says “Ubuntu Server for IBM Z and LinuxONE is priced at $19,500 per drawer per year, covering unlimited usage of Ubuntu within that drawer, 24x7 Ubuntu Advantage Advanced support services and regular security and reliability fixes from Canonical.”.

Does this apply to support only?  We do not need support for this software, we just want to be able to use it for a testing environment to help our end customers.

Many thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu is free, the price is for support.

Comment: Yes, that applies only to support.  You can deploy an infinite number of ubuntu systems without any paid support for free if you have the infrastructure to maintain the systems (but that's not factored into Ubuntu's *costs* per-se.)

Comment: From the same web site, section FAQs: *"Support Agreement (UA) [is] required to run Ubuntu on z Systems when in a production environment"*. Whether your environment is to be considered "production" or not is not explained, but it usually comes back to whether you derive income from it in some way.